# Unable to use 'User-managed identity' with Azure Function App

Tags: azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to use 'User-managed identity' with my function app. The managed id has contributor access at resource-group level where function is hosted. It's a powershell function and at the moment it only has

```
Write-Host "Hello World"
```

When I run my function I get below error:

```
2021-10-05T13:34:15Z   [Warning]   WARNING: Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations' with error 'ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed.
Status: 400 (Bad Request)

Headers:
Date: Tue, 05 Oct 2021 13:34:14 GMT
Content-Length: 133
'
2021-10-05T13:34:16Z   [Error]   ERROR: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed.
Status: 400 (Bad Request)

Headers:
Date: Tue, 05 Oct 2021 13:34:14 GMT
Content-Length: 133


Exception             : 
    Type           : Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException
    TargetSite     : 
        Name          : FailWrapAndThrow
        DeclaringType : Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope, Azure.Identity, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8
        MemberType    : Method
        Module        : Azure.Identity.dll
    StackTrace     : 
   at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Authenticators.MsalAccessTokenAcquirer.GetAccessTokenAsync(String callerClassName, String parametersLog, TokenCredential tokenCredential, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String tenantId, String userId, String homeAccountId)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Factories.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate(IAzureAccount account, IAzureEnvironment environment, String tenant, SecureString password, String promptBehavior, Action`1 promptAction, IAzureTokenCache tokenCache, String resourceId)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient.AcquireAccessToken(IAzureAccount account, IAzureEnvironment environment, String tenantId, SecureString password, String promptBehavior, Action`1 promptAction, String resourceId)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient.ListAccountTenants(IAzureAccount account, IAzureEnvironment environment, SecureString password, String promptBehavior, Action`1 promptAction)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient.Login(IAzureAccount account, IAzureEnvironment environment, String tenantId, String subscriptionId, String subscriptionName, SecureString password, Boolean skipValidation, Action`1 promptAction, String name, Boolean shouldPopulateContextList, Int32 maxContextPopulation, String authScope)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.<>c__DisplayClass118_2.<ExecuteCmdlet>b__5()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunFromThreadPoolDispatchLoop(Thread threadPoolThread, ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.<>c__DisplayClass118_0.<ExecuteCmdlet>b__1(AzureRmProfile localProfile, RMProfileClient profileClient, String name)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.<>c__DisplayClass126_0.<SetContextWithOverwritePrompt>b__0(AzureRmProfile prof, RMProfileClient client)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Common.AzureContextModificationCmdlet.ModifyContext(Action`2 contextAction)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.SetContextWithOverwritePrompt(Action`3 setContextAction)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand.ExecuteCmdlet()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.<>c__3`1.<ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob>b__3_0(T c)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet, Action`1 executor)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.CmdletExtensions.ExecuteSynchronouslyOrAsJob[T](T cmdlet)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
    Message        : ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed.
                     Status: 400 (Bad Request)
                     
                     Headers:
                     Date: Tue, 05 Oct 2021 13:34:14 GMT
                     Content-Length: 133
                     
    InnerException : 
        Type       : Azure.RequestFailedException
        Status     : 400
        TargetSite : 
            Name          : MoveNext
            DeclaringType : Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentitySource+<HandleResponseAsync>d__10, Azure.Identity, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8
            MemberType    : Method
            Module        : Azure.Identity.dll
        StackTrace : 
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentitySource.HandleResponseAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, Response response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentitySource.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityClient.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        Message    : Service request failed.
                     Status: 400 (Bad Request)
                     
                     Headers:
                     Date: Tue, 05 Oct 2021 13:34:14 GMT
                     Content-Length: 133
                     
        Source     : Azure.Identity
        HResult    : -2146233088
    Source         : Azure.Identity
    HResult        : -2146233088
CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], AuthenticationFailedException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
InvocationInfo        : 
    MyCommand        : Connect-AzAccount
    ScriptLineNumber : 16
    OffsetInLine     : 5
    HistoryId        : 1
    ScriptName       : C:\home\site\wwwroot\profile.ps1
    Line             : Connect-AzAccount -Identity
                       
    PositionMessage  : At C:\home\site\wwwroot\profile.ps1:16 char:5
                       +     Connect-AzAccount -Identity
                       +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    PSScriptRoot     : C:\home\site\wwwroot
    PSCommandPath    : C:\home\site\wwwroot\profile.ps1
    InvocationName   : Connect-AzAccount
    CommandOrigin    : Internal
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, C:\home\site\wwwroot\profile.ps1: line 16
PipelineIterationInfo : 





2021-10-05T13:34:17Z   [Error]   Errors reported while executing profile.ps1. See logs for detailed errors. Profile location: C:\home\site\wwwroot\profile.ps1.
2021-10-05T13:34:17Z   [Information]   INFORMATION: Hello World
```

I have followed the steps listed in the [doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-functions%2Ftoc.json&tabs=dotnet#obtain-tokens-for-azure-resources) and have also double checked the function app does have IDENTITY_ENDPOINT and IDENTITY_HEADER values set.

For the life of me I can't get this to work. It does however works fine with 'System-assigned managed identity'.

I have also tried combinations of Connect-AzAccount and Set-AzContext commands, I end up getting same error.

Is any one able to point out what am I missing here, it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How are you passing the client_id of your managed identity?

Comment: you need to **assign** the managed user identity to the function. Go the function and selection the "Idenity" menu under the "Settings" section.  You'll see a "User Assigned" tab.  Add it there.

Comment: @udayxhegde can you please elaborate how it needs to be passed. At the moment I dont think i am doing that.

Comment: Rfd, it looks like you figured out how to pass the client_id, based on you adding an answer below, let me know if you still need any help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Got it working, it needed below in run.ps1

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId <Managed-User Identity> -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 7):

On my side I was trying to connect with cosmos DB client

But the `ManagedIdentityClientId` parameter was missing in the client method

```
string userAssignedClientId = "<USER_ASSIGNED_CLIENT_ID>";
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId });

new CosmosClient
```

Answer (score 5):

When you use a user assigned managed identity you still need to specify which identity you want to use with what credential (since you can have more than one user assigned identity attached). To identify what identity to use, you simply specify the client ID of the manage identity.

This will depend on what method you use but the AZURE_CLIENT_ID environment variable can be used to guide the Azure.Identity package to select the user assigned managed identity you want to use.

Answer (score 3):

For user assigned identity connections you need to add environment variables for `<CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>__credential` and `<CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>__clientId` otherwise the function host will default to trying system assigned identity.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=azurewebjobsstorage#common-properties-for-identity-based-connections

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Owns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039094/owns) supporting your answer adding the screenshot on how to add the user identity in function app settings.

[image]

Also,
Need to Enable the System Assigned as well by default it will in off status need to turn it on and save as shown below

[image]

Below is the sample code on how to use the managed identity in Azure functions

```
# Replace the built-in code for Azure function
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Timer)

# Get the current universal time in the default string format
$currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
# The 'IsPastDue' property is 'true' when the current function invocation is later than scheduled.
if ($Timer.IsPastDue) {
    Write-Host "PowerShell timer is running late!"
}

# This function app is using 'Managed Service Identity' to connect to the Azure SQL Database.
# Used help from following resources in setting up 'Managed Service Identity'
# [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi)
# [https://www.azurecorner.com/using-managed-service-identity-in-azure-functions-to-access-azure-sql-database/](https://www.azurecorner.com/using-managed-service-identity-in-azure-functions-to-access-azure-sql-database/)
# [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=powershell)
$resourceURI = "[https://database.windows.net/](https://database.windows.net/)"
$tokenAuthURI = $env:MSI_ENDPOINT + "?resource=$resourceURI&api-version=2017-09-01"
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{"Secret"="$env:MSI_SECRET"} -Uri $tokenAuthURI
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source =azuresqlservername.database.windows.net ; Initial Catalog = azuresqldatabasename"
$SqlConnection.AccessToken = $AccessToken
$SqlConnection.Open()
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "ALTER INDEX ALL ON testRebuild REBUILD;"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
```

For further information check the [Managed Identity link.](https://sqlworldwide.com/how-to-use-managed-identity-with-azure-function-app/)

Comment: The managed identity is already assigned under 'user assigned' tab. I don't understand why are you proposing turning on 'managed identity' as well. I don't want to use managed identitiy as it's lifecycle will be attached to Function app. I want a persistent id can be used by any function and will not get deleted if function is deleted.